# Alternativa para If/Else

Tags: c#, if, estilo-de-codificação, else

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
private void maskedTextBoxEAN_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(maskedTextBoxEAN.Text))
        if (!ValidaEAN13.CalculateChecksum(maskedTextBoxEAN.Text))
            CaixaMensagemDeErro.Mensagem("O código EAN digitado não é valido.");        
}
```

Ele funciona, porem gostaria de saber se existe uma forma melhor de fazer isto com menos `if/else`, ou até sem.

Tem como?

Comment: Vc pode usar o operador ternário `?` e `:` mas não sei se é uma boa opção para ifs aninhado.

Comment: Isso não é if/else, é somente if aninhado. e para isso existe o operado && ou || para verificar mais de uma condição.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem `if/else` não deve ser possível, mas você pode você pode usar o [operador `&&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2a723cdk.aspx) para fazer num `if` somente:

```
private void maskedTextBoxEAN_Leave(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(maskedTextBoxEAN.Text) &&
        !ValidaEAN13.CalculateChecksum(maskedTextBoxEAN.Text))
            CaixaMensagemDeErro.Mensagem("O código EAN digitado não é valido.");
}
```

Dependendo de como o método `CalculateChecksum` trata o argumento, o `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` pode não ser necessário.

Como sugestão, você pode usar o [`ErrorProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) para informar o usuário do erro.

```
private void maskedTextBoxEAN_Leave(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidaEAN13.CalculateChecksum(maskedTextBoxEAN.Text){
        errorProvider1.SetError(maskedTextBoxEAN, "O código EAN digitado não é valido.");
        //e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(maskedTextBoxEAN, String.Empty);
        //e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Você pode também cancelar a ação do usuário ao definir como `true` a [propriedade `Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) do controle.